# Leaving to India from Germany without house de-registration

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card

I have got Blue card (residence permit) in Germany. I came from India in March and now wants to leave Germany back to my home country because of all these covid situations.

First I will leave my apartment in Germany (do I need to deregister it ?)

Will work from India for 3-4 months for the same organisation for which I was working in Germany. And then will leave the German organisation. Can I do so after leaving Germany from India?

Comment: Are you asking if you can de-register from Germany? Or if you can continue to work for your German employer from India? Or both?

Comment: @Traveller- I am asking that currently, I have an address in Germany, I will leave this address and will go to India. I am asking can I work (for some time) from India if I don't have any german address but have Valid Blue card

Comment: Could you please tell what exactly happened afterwards. As I am also having similar kind of situation at present. Your experience can help me.
I have to go to India and work for the same company for around 6 months and i do not want to pay for the apartment so i wish to vacate and deregister myself but afterwards i will come back and look for new apartment later. Is this fine to have no address in Germany while you are not here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Sonam- I went to India, but didn't vacant the apartment, as per my best source it was not legally possible to deregister and work from home. I did work from home from India and paid the rent in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer reside in your apartment (i.e. you are giving it up), then you must deregister it within a 2 week period after leaving (earliest: one week before leaving).

Please note that when you **permanently** leave Germany your residence permit **expires**, since you have terminated your residence.

This will have **no** effect on your continuing employment while working from India, since you don't need a german work permit when working from outside of Germany. That is solely a matter between you and your employer.

Comment: Sir, so it means I can get German salary, health insurance and social security even if I don't have a house or apartment in Germany?

Comment: @VipulJain No, not necessarily. The laws of the country you are working in would apply primarily. The salary would be based on what you agree to with the employer. Taxes, pensions and health insurance your local laws would apply.

Comment: Okay, great Sir, I thought I can work for Germany if I have blue-card until 1 year even If I am staying in some other country

Comment: There is a [tax treaty](https://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/pages/international-taxation/dtaa.aspx) between India and Germany. It should prevent double taxation, and also help with determining where the worker is resident for tax purposes.

Comment: (+1) By definition, a residence permit can only “expire” because of the passage of time and the end of its period of validity. I think “becomes invalid” would be a better translation for "*erlöschen*” in this context.

Comment: @Relaxed [§51 (1) AufthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1050): *The residence title **expires** [erlischt] in the following cases:* of which 8 cases are listed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I know exactly where that's coming from, I even mentioned the verb *erlöschen* explicitely to avoid any ambiguity. The whole point of my comment was to explain that this translation was wrong. You can use that comment to improve your answer, you can engage with my argument if you feel like discussing it, you can even ignore it entirely if you prefer but merely restating the same thing doesn't meaningfully address the point I raised.

Comment: @Relaxed It is the translation provided by the Language Service of the Federal Ministry of the Interior. The specfic law defines 8 different conditions. If you already know that, then why do you claim **a)** the translation is wrong **b)** there is only one condition? I prefer to use the terminology used in semi-official translations.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I didn't claim (b) at all, quite the opposite. The very fact there are 8 different cases (which go way beyond what's proprely called “expiring” in English) is precisely why the translation is wrong. The confusion only confirms that. I would still recommend using terminology that is not erroneous nor misleading, even if it is a slight departure from that used by the “Language Service of the Federal Ministry of the Interior”.

Comment: @Relaxed Sorry, but I disagree. Google Translate **Gültigkeit Erlischt am 23.03.21** -> *Validity Expires on 03/23/21*

Comment: @MarkJohnson Google Translate is not a good way to address this question (to say the least) but I have no issue with that translation. That's indeed exactly what “expire” means as I explained in my initial comment so where is the disagreement here? On the other hand, that word doesn't properly express the other meanings of “*erlöschen*”.

Comment: @Relaxed The disagreement is based in your initial comment: `By definition, a residence permit can only “expire” because of the passage of time and the end of its period of validity`, which **does not** correspond to the legal definition in the relevant law **nor** to the translation provided by the responsible authority (and matches that of Google Translate) that inforces this law and you do so as a 'statement of fact' **without** citing a verifiable source that confirms your claim.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I have the feeling we are running in circles, it's amazing how such a simple point could generate so much discussion without ever getting to the actual substance of the issue. My comment *By definition, a residence permit can only “expire” because of the passage of time and the end of its period of validity* is not about the meaning of the law, it is about the meaning of the word “expire” in English. If that's what's in doubt, [any dictionary will confirm it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expire). Any issue with this?

Comment: @Relaxed Yes we are. But my usage of the word 'expires' was in the context of a residence permit and not in the context of a general dictionary meaning. Thus, I believe, yozr initial comment of off topic for this question/answer (more appropriate for [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: @MarkJohnson  In the context of a residence permit, it means the same thing, your usage of the word “expire” is simply improper in English. You're free to ask on English language and usage if you need any clarification but I don't, that's perfectly clear to me and you have offered no reason to doubt it. All the examples (very much including your Google Translate quote, for what it's worth) come from similar formal/legal contexts and points in the same direction, i.e. “expires” *only* applies to the end of a fixed period of validity.

Comment: @Relaxed Not mine only, but also the translation provided by the Language Service of the Federal Ministry of the Interior of the relavent law and other translation services: [Erlöschen : Wörterbuch / Dictionary (BEOLINGUS, TU Chemnitz)](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=Erl%F6schen&iservice=): **erlischt**: **expires**; becomes extinct ; lapses ; terminates ; is terminated

Comment: @Relaxed Both though *erlöscht* (*expired*) and *nichtig* (*void*) a document **becomes invalid** (**wird ungültig**). Through the first (*expired*), the initial date of expiry is replaced (the use of the document up to this point is legitimate). Through the second (*void*), the document was never valid and therefore the usage was always illegitimate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Google Translate (even though this example actually supports my point) or German-English dictionaries are not a good way to determine the meaning of an English word. You dismiss a high-quality English dictionary but what you are offering is a ludicrous way to determine whether a translation is appropriate. There is no one-to-one correspondence between words in different languages! Do you have any clue of the meaning of the word “expire” in a legal context which does not rely in a completely circular fashion on the meaning of the word “*erlöschen*”?

Comment: In particular, “*Through the first (expired), the initial date of expiry is replaced (the use of the document up to this point is legitimate)*” makes no sense and is improper in English. When a document “expires”, it's because it reaches the end of the period of validity that was set initially. Since, as you repeated (and I agree), that's not what *erlöschen* means in a German legal context, “expire“ is not a good translation, Federal Ministry of the Interior notwithstanding.

Comment: Note that Duolinguo offers a better translation (and further support for my point): “is terminated”. This doesn't mean that “expires” is synonymous with “is terminated” but it does lean that “*erlöschen*” has a broader meaning than the word “expire”, which has been my point all along.